# how to calculate tableview cell height and label height automatic

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, height, cell

sorry,I am s beginner of swift.
I want to get chat bubble view,but I can't make it neat to me. 
how to make the tableviewcell auto update height 
Thanks a lot!

[image: view like this]

[image: last two line is emoji]

**Viewcontroller.swift**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let content = contents[indexPath.row] as Message
    let contentWidth:CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width*0.590
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.font = fontTalkContent
    label.text = content.content
    label.sizeToFit()
    var uiHeight:CGFloat = (label.frame.height <= defaultChatroomIconHeight) ? defaultContentHeight : label.frame.height

}

class ChatContentTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
var labelContent:UILabel = { ()->UILabel in
    let ui:UILabel = ChatContent()
    ui.font = defaultTextFont
    ui.numberOfLines = 0
    ui.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    ui.layer.cornerRadius = dafaultLabelContentRadius
    ui.layer.masksToBounds = true
    ui.isHidden = false
    return ui
}()

override func layoutSubviews()
{
    super.layoutSubviews()
     bulidLoad()

}
func bulidload() {

    labelContent.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)

    labelContent.sizeToFit()

    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[labelContent]-padding-[icon]-padding-|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
            addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[labelDatetime]-padding-[icon]-padding-|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
            addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-topPadding-[labelContent]-contentAndDatePadding-[labelDatetime]-dateAndBottomPaddding-|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
            addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-topPadding-[icon]", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
}
}

class ChatContent:UILabel {
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame:frame)
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    numberOfLines = 0
    isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
    let insets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: defaultContentPadding, left: defaultPadding, bottom: defaultContentPadding, right: defaultPadding)

    super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
}
}
```

Comment: Use self-sizing for UITableViewCell, for tutorial see this: http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

Comment: where are setting the text to label can you please add code of cellforRowAtIndexPath and CellWillDisplay which you have written.

Answer (score 1):

Use UITableViewAutomaticDimension

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Set constraint of label

2.make no of lines(label) is equal to Zero.

3.Add these code in `viewDidLoad():`

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 88.0
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60 

tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

don't forget to set label noOfLines to 0 of cell

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign height dynamically as per content, then please follow below instructions...

For dynamic size of UITableViewCell required two things.

1. Setting the the right constraint of your view inside the table view cell (mostly it includes giving your view proper top , bottom & trailing constraints)
2. Calling these properties of TableView in `viewDidLoad()`

   ```
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80 //assign as per your requirements
   ```

For more in-detail reference please go through this [Link1](http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/) and [Link2](https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells).

Hope it help you :)